# How to edit and run a WordPress site on my local machine using PhpStorm

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, phpstorm

I have been doing some research on editing WordPress sites locally and found that PhpStorm is one of the best IDE's out there for this.

The problem I am having is that after downloading my entire WordPress site to my local machine I am unable to even find an option to import it and run it in PhpStorm. I am also struggling to find comprehensive tutorials out there for this so I would appreciate it if someone can at least point me in the right direction so that I can start making progress.

Comment: Just use "Open" from the Welcome screen (visible when all projects are closed) and point to the project root folder -- PhpStorm will create a project from those existing files. The rest can be configured later: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/preparing-to-use-wordpress.html

Comment: What do you mean by "import it"? Why not open a new project and copy all the files into that project?

Answer (score 3):

JetBrains has already written a very comprehensive documentation on how to get started with WordPress in PhpStorm.

Documentation Link : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/preparing-to-use-wordpress.html

This is the most useful part for you [Download and install WordPress](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/preparing-to-use-wordpress.html#downloading-and-installing-wordpress) but I would recommend to go through the doc in its entirety.

To run WordPress you will have to setup a local development server. You can use the following.

1. [Laragon](https://laragon.org/)
2. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)
3. [Local by flywheel](https://localwp.com/pro-for-everyone/) (Its pro version is free now.)